# Using jQuery to determine the index of a link based on the link text

Tags: jquery

Given the text of a link (e.g. "Two" in the html below), I want to be able to determine the index of the associated link in the collection of links.  For example link "Two" should return 1 (assuming a 0-based index).

```
<div id='linkCollection'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='linkone.html'>One</a></li>
      <li><a href='linktwo.html'>Two</a></li>
      <li><a href='linkthree.html'>Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can select the collection of links using `$('#linkCollection ul li')`, but I don't see how to "search" for specific text and return the index.  (I'm sure I'm missing something very basic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
$('#linkCollection ul li:contains("Two")').index()
```

This uses the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [index function](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li>a').each(function(){
  if($(this).text()=="Two"){
     var myid=$(this).index();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello jalperin'm new here, I'm using google translator to talk to you, sorry for the bad english ..

To retrieve the index:

```
$('#linkCollection ul li').click(function(){
  var index = $('#linkCollection ul li').index(this);
  alert(index);
});
```